# Moving rigidbody in Unity project with Gear VR touchpad

Tags: unity-game-engine, oculus, gear-vr

In Unity 5.3.3, how do you get the Gear VR touchpad to move a character/rigidbody?

Comment: [Input.GetTouch](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input.GetTouch.html) ?

Comment: Take a look at http://talesfromtherift.com/gearvr-input-touchpad/

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is what you want: [Interaction in VR](http://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/topics/virtual-reality/interaction-vr?playlist=22946)

> The Gear VR has a touchpad on the side of the HMD. This appears as a mouse to Unity, and so we can use the following:

- Input.mousePosition
- Input.GetMouseButtonDown
- Input.GetMouseButtonUp

> With Gear VR we also need to get swipe data from the touchpad. We’ve
>   included a sample script called VRInput which deals with swipes, taps,
>   and double-taps. It also allows directional arrows and Left-Ctrl
>   (Fire1 in Unity default input terms) on a keyboard (or Left Mouse
>   button) to trigger swipes and taps.